# Blank Line in ProxyAddress AD Attributes

Tags: active-directory

I made Powershell script for update de ProxyAdrress attribute in the AD, but the script save a extra blank line.  How can a remove that blank line?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using split for separating two proxy addresses.
Same Blank Space I am also getting if I am using `–split “,”`
[image]

**Solution:** Do not use `-split “,”` Getting the expected output
[image]

Reference : https://activedirectorypro.com/how-to-bulk-update-proxyaddresses-attribute/